# PHP: how can a class reference its own name?

Tags: php

In PHP, how can a class reference its own name?

For example, what would the method look like to do this?

```
Dog::sayOwnClassName();
//echos "Dog";
```

### Update

I see that everyone is saying `get_class($this)`. But that's not correct. That would work if I were creating an **instance** of Dog. I'm asking about calling a method of the Dog class itself. If `Dog` extends `Mammal`, then a call to `get_class($this)` inside the `Dog` class will return 'Mammal.'.

In other words:

- I'm not asking "what's the class of the Dog class," to which the answer is, "the Dog class is a member of the Mammal class."
- I'm also not asking "given an instance of Dog the dog class (called Rover), what is its class?", to which the answer is "Dog."
- What I'm asking is, "can the Dog class itself tell me 'my name is Dog?'"

For example:

```
class Mammal {    
  public function find_by_id($id){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $myclass . " WHERE `id` = " . $id;
    //(etc)
    return $matching_object;
  }
}

class Dog extends Mammal {
//find_by_id method should know to do a SELECT from Dog table     
}
```

### Update 2

Yacoby's suggestion of `get_called_class()` was correct. Here's how it works in the example I gave.

```
class Mammal {    
      public function find_by_id($id){
        $myclass = get_called_class();
        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $myclass . " WHERE `id` = " . $id;
        //(etc)
        return $matching_object;
      }
    }

    class Dog extends Mammal {
    //find_by_id knows to do a SELECT from Dog table
    //and will return the correct dog object     
    }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Three options, [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php), [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) or the [magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) `__CLASS__`

Of those three [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) is the one you want when dealing using a static function, although unfortuantely it does have a requirement of a PHP version of at least 5.3.0

---

#### get_called_class()

If you need to get the class in a static function when the class may be derived it is slightly different as `self` is resolved to the class name where it was placed (See [Limitations of self::](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php)). To work around this issue you need to use the function from PHP 5.3.0 [`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php).

If you cannot use PHP 5.3.0 or greater you may find you cannot make the function static and still have it achieve the results you want.

---

#### get_class()

`get_class()` returns the name of the actual class that the object is, irrespective of where the function call is.

```
class Animal{
     public function sayOwnClassName(){
         echo get_class($this);
     }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
}


$d = new Dog();
$d->sayOwnClassName(); //echos Dog

$a = new Animal();
$a->sayOwnClassName(); //echos Animal
```

`get_class` can also be used without a parameter, which would at first glance seem to indicate it would with static functions (as there is no need to pass `$this`), however when used without a parameter it works in the same way as `__CLASS__`

```
class Animal{
     public static function sayOwnClassName(){
         echo get_class();
     }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
}


Dog::sayOwnClassName(); //echos Animal
Animal::sayOwnClassName(); //echos Animal
```

---

#### __CLASS__

`__CLASS__` always expands to the name of the class where `__CLASS__` was resolved, even when inheritance is taken into account.

```
class Animal{
     public function sayOwnClassName(){
         echo __CLASS__; //will always expand to Animal
     }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
}

$d = new Dog();
$d->sayOwnClassName(); //echos Animal

$a = new Animal();
$a->sayOwnClassName(); //echos Animal
```

---

Comment: +1 for mentioning the magic constant in addition to get_class and the better examples

Comment: Yacoby - you're instantiating Dog. I'm not.

Comment: @Nathan I missed that complexity, my apologies. I have added some more information at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Yacoby - great! Thanks - that did the trick. Would you mind editing your answer to just show the get_called_class() part so that people who find this later get straight to that?

Comment: @Nathan Done (Well not quite, but is shows the get_called_class part far more clearly)

Answer (score 2):

```
echo get_class($this);
```

Comment: I'm not instantiating Dog - I'm using a class-level method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's get_class($Object)

Then there's __CLASS__ when used within a class

Or you could make a method that would return __CLASS__

Answer (score 1):

use the magic constant `__CLASS__`

Answer (score 0):

```
public function sayClassName()
{
    echo get_class($this);
}
```

[get_class() php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)